# Using Parental Controls with TOR

Tags: proxy, privacy, parental-controls

A friend of mine wants to protect his children's anonymity with TOR. However, he is unwilling to stop using parental controls to log what websites his children visit and block adult websites. Is it possible to have the best of both worlds?

What he wants is a solution that allows his children to tunnel Internet traffic through TOR, while still blocking unsavory websites and logging websites visited. He understands that logging undermines a significant amount of privacy, but is hopeful that a more private solution, such that only he can access his children's web history, is possible.

His current parental controls solution is OpenDNS parental controls.

**TL;DR**

Can TOR be used in combination with adult content filtering and web monitoring software? If so, is it possible the these parental controls could be private, so that only the parent can read his children's logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the OpenDNS service with TOR because TOR uses its own DNS.  You can, however, use any of the freely available parental control packages that install on the PS itself.

Comment: I understand that the TOR browser does. But, what about the TOR daemon? If I tunnel all traffic through the TOR SOCKS proxy, would OpenDNS still work?

Comment: The TOR proxy provides its own DNS server.  Using a different DNS server seriously compromises your privacy to the point that using TOR really has no purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting an answer like that, but it was worth a try.